# ORMLite Select Distinct Fields

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I have a SQLite table (on Android) that has numerous fields, but certain fields are repeated/denormalized.  I would like to select a distinct set of this data and use them as actual objects.

**Example**

*books table*

```
title            summary        author
Little Johnny    A funny kid    Johnny Himself
Big Johnny       A funny adult  Johnny Himself
```

I would like to extract one author from this list ("Johnny Himself") and would expect I should be able to do this with ORMLite instead of manually with Java.

Comment: Go through statementBuilder with distinct().columns(...) return empty data ? - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ormlite-user/ryfsT0gXCaY

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I would like to select a distinct set of this data and use them as actual objects.

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) supports a [`distinct()` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#distinct%28%29) on the `QueryBuilder` that should do what you want.  So your code would look something like:

```
List<Book> results = booksDao.queryBuilder()
    .distinct().selectColumns("author").query();
```

In this case, the resulting `Book` objects would only have the `author` field set and not the `id` field or anything else.  If you just wanted the author names instead of objects then you could do:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults =
    booksDao.queryRaw("SELECT DISTINCT author FROM books");
for (String[] resultColumns : rawResults) {
    String author = resultColumns[0];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my application code

```
public class DbHelper<T> {
    private Class<T> c;
    private DatabaseHelper db;
    public DbHelper(Class<T> c) {
        this.c = c;
        db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();
    }
```

This is a good idea

```
public List<T> queryForBuilderDistinct(int offset, int limit, String ColumnsName,
       String orderName, boolean isAsc) {
    try {
        Dao<T, Integer> dao = db.getDao(c);
        QueryBuilder<T, Integer> queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();
        if (offset != 0) {
            queryBuilder.offset((long) offset);
        }
        if (limit != 0) {
            queryBuilder.limit((long) limit);
        }
        if (orderName != null) {
            queryBuilder.orderBy(orderName, isAsc);
        }
        queryBuilder.distinct().selectColumns(ColumnsName);
        return dao.query(queryBuilder.prepare());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LogUtil.e(TAG, "queryForBuilderDistinct", e);
    }
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```