# ORMLite DISTINCT With Where Condition

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I am developing an android project using ORMLite and i have a problem to figure out. There is a picture below and how can i use DISTINCT sql query in **ORMLite**? 
I have some parameters giving to where condition and according to this conditions i am getting number list...

In this picture you are going to see some numbers and some of these numbers are same but i don't want to get same numbers so how can i use DISTINCT in ORMLite with where condition.

Thanks for helping

Also some of my code is like this:

```
  private void modalShowEbat() {
    dbHelper = (DBHelper) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DBHelper.class);
    RuntimeExceptionDao<Segment, Integer> segmentDao = dbHelper.getSegmentExceptionDao();
    List<Segment> list = segmentDao.queryForEq(Constant.QUERY_SEGMENT, editTextSegment.getText().toString().trim());

    final CharSequence items[] = new CharSequence[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        items[i] = list.get(i).getColumnEbat();
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Segment seçiniz");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // the user clicked on colors[which]
            editTextEbat.setText(items[which].toString());
            if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

[This is my image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYOD0.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORMLite Select Distinct Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190786/ormlite-select-distinct-fields)

Comment: I wrote this code but did not work as I want... Because i have to use where condition but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I solved my problem with below code. Maybe you can say this is long way for this. I wrote my code like below because i couldn't do other ways(using .distinct() method in ORMLite or other ORMLite's method)

If you have any other ways to solve this, i am waiting your suggestions. Thanks for everybody, happy coding...

```
private void modalShowEbat() {
    dbHelper = (DBHelper) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DBHelper.class);
    RuntimeExceptionDao<Segment, Integer> segmentDao = dbHelper.getSegmentExceptionDao();
    List<Segment> list = segmentDao.queryForEq(Constant.QUERY_SEGMENT, editTextSegment.getText().toString().trim());

    GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults = segmentDao.queryRaw("SELECT DISTINCT Ebat FROM Segment WHERE Segment = ? ", editTextSegment.getText().toString().trim());
    final CharSequence items[] = new CharSequence[list.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (String[] resultColumns : rawResults) {
        String author = resultColumns[0];
        items[i] = author;
        i++;
    }
    int newLenght = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        if (items[j] != null) {
            newLenght++;
        }
    }
    final CharSequence newItems[] = new CharSequence[newLenght];
    for (int j = 0; j < newLenght; j++) {
        if (items[j] != null) {
            newItems[j] = items[j];
        }
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose Segment");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(newItems, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // the user clicked on colors[which]
            editTextEbat.setText(newItems[which].toString());
            if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
segmentDao.queryBuilder().distinct().where().eq("name", "value").query();
```